# Does the return value of a MATLAB function depend on how it's called?

Tags: matlab, function

```
A = imread(filename, fmt)

[X, map] = imread(...)
```

The above is in the synopsis part of `imread`, which seems to say that the return value of a MATLAB function depends on how it's called? Is that true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMREAD function is defined as

```
function [X, map, alpha] = imread(varargin)
```

In your 2 examples A and X will be the same, but in the second case there will be additional variable `map`.

There is a way in MATLAB to define variable output if you use [VARARGOUT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/varargout.html) in function definition:

```
function varargout = foo(x)
```

So you can output different values based on some condition in the function body.

This is a silly example, but it illustrates the consept:

```
function varargout = foo(a,b)
if a>b
    varargout{1} = a+b;
    varargout{2} = a-b;
else
    varargout{1} = a;
    varargout{2} = b;
end
```

Then

```
[x,y] = foo(2,3)
x =
     2
y =
     3
[x,y] = foo(3,2)
x =
     5
y =
     1
```

The output arguments can be even different data types.

Another example with condition based on number of output variables:

```
function varargout = foo(a,b)
if nargout < 2
    varargout{1} = a+b;
else
    varargout{1} = a;
    varargout{2} = b;
end
```

Then

```
[x,y] = foo(2,3)
x =
     2
y =
     3
x = foo(2,3)
x =
     5
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, matlab has a mechanism to provide variable amount results, and also for the input parameters.

You can use it yourself when you write functions, see the documentation about [narg*](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/nargin.html) on Mathwork to learn more.

Take for example the [histogram](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/hist.html) function

```
> hist(1:100); % generates a plot with the 10 bins
> hist(1:100, 4); % generates a plot with 4 bins
> fillrate = hist(1:100, 4); % returns the fill rate for the 4 bins
> [fillrate, center] = hist(1:100,4); % returns the fill rate and the bins center in 2 differen variables
```

Comment: Let me confirm,is it true the return value can be different even for the same input parameters?I've never seen such a feature in any other languages yet.

Comment: Yep, that is true. If it helps, you can think of the results list as a special kind of argument.

Comment: What's the name of this feature?I need it to google for more info:)

Comment: Google for varargout. But note this is not the case for imread.

Comment: This is also the case in Perl, to some extent - you can google around for `wantarray` and context.

Comment: @user198729: Here's a link that may be useful: http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/bresuxt-1.html

Comment: It's by function definition. See my answer.